# Publishing issues with Metro-style Apps

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, publish, microsoft-metro

I have just finished a metro style App in Windows Developer Preview (for the upcoming version of Windows) and have run into a problem when publishing my app.

I have followed the instructions in the Windows Dev Center, and it "published" successfully. However, upon clicking my App's Tile in the Apps section of the Start screen, the Windows Store App loads, instead of *my* app.

Has anybody else run into this, or similar issues? Are there any known causes/solutions?

Edit: Yes, I *have* chosen the publish locally option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because windows 8 is not published yet.when 8 is released your app will be accesible

Comment: That is some sad news. I want it now! Oh well, atleast I can sleep at night now, knowing there's nothing wrong :-) Thanks very much @ismail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to side load an app on any Windows 8 Dev machine as long as that machine has a valid developer license. I don't think you have a license issue, since a license issue normally results in a obvious error message like "You need a license, bro".

A license is generated for you automatically when you are using Visual Studio. However, if the device you are testing on does not have VS or has never run it then you will need to generate a license using a power shell script. See this link for more information on generating licenses.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/7be92f16-7179-4d74-9915-c6f21e0f4c55